# Where must I declare my global variables?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm confused if I'm doing the right thing now in the way that I'm declaring global variables...

I did this:

```
class Addition:

    global a,b
    a,b=1,3

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add(self):
        return a+b
```

Is this the right way to declare my global variables? Or should I put them inside the **init**() construct? like this?

```
class Addition:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=2

    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

Which should I use ? or is there a better way in declaring global variables than these two? I wanted to make my program as readable as it can be for others to easily understand and for good practice.

Comment: Are we talking about globals or instance attributes here? Your second example uses the latter, something completely different from the former. What should happen when you have **more than one instance**? With globals, there is no point, because all state is shared between the instances.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't yet understand the difference between class instances and globals; your question makes no sense as it stands anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using global variables at all, unless you can avoid them.

Your second example does not in fact use global variables. That is what you should do.